# WebRTC/Janus on iOS

Tags: ios, webrtc, janus-gateway

What are my options implementing WebRTC (Janus specifically) in my iOS app?

From what I've gathered, using the WebRTC library made by Google is hard and may fail. Also the fact that the backend uses Janus, I don't know how much work I'd have to do to get the basic WebRTC compatible with the Janus layer.

Also, does WebRTC work in Safari/WK webviews in iOS 11/12? I don't want to stream from the app, I only want to view a stream.

Comment: Janus is NOT a WebRTC "front-end" implementation itself.. It's a backend and a protocol.. For front-end (iOS), you'd need Google's web-rtc and starscream socket library. Then you implement janus-protocol over the websocket to get the candidates and flow going and you pass that to Google's WebRTC and use AVFoundation to stream the video.. So yeah, you'd have to do some manual stuff.. and Google's WebRTC works just fine.. I use it (albeit without Janus).

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. You mentioned that you use Google’s WebRTC, is this the regular WebRTC or the AppRTC library? Also do you know of any good tutorials or documentations for WebRTC?

Comment: It's not AppRTC. It's regular WebRTC that connects to our own WebRTC server. I read on it from Firefox tutorial.

Comment: @Brandon I'm assuming it's a Swift/Objective C article. Do you mind if you linked me to it? Thanks